# If I simultaneously kill my opponent and deck myself at the same time, is the game drawn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say my opponent has 2 life left and I have 0 cards left in my library. I cast [Electrolyze](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElectrolyze%5d) doing two damage to opponent. It resolves.

Does he die before I deck myself, or do we simultaneously lose? That is, does the wording on Electrolyze mean "Electrolyze deals 2 damage divided as you choose among one or two targets *and then* you draw a card", or do both effects occur simultaneously?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a draw.

While the 'lethal' effects do not occur simultaneously, the state-based actions that check whether a player loses only happen after the spell resolves, not during its resolution:

> 608.2. If the object that's resolving is an instant spell, a sorcery spell, or an ability, its resolution may involve several steps.
>
> 116.3b The active player receives priority after a spell or ability (other than a mana ability) resolves.
>
> 704.3. Whenever a player would get priority (see rule 116, "Timing and Priority"), the game checks for any of the listed conditions for state-based actions, then performs all applicable state-based actions simultaneously as a single event.

After Electrolyze resolve, state-based actions are checked:

> 104.3b If a player's life total is 0 or less, that player loses the game the next time a player would receive priority. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)
>
> 104.3c If a player is required to draw more cards than are left in their library, they draw the remaining cards and then lose the game the next time a player would receive priority. (This is a state-based action. See rule 704.)
>
> 104.4a If all the players remaining in a game lose simultaneously, the game is a draw.