# what if you an your opponent die at the same times

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Suppose my opponent and I have a life total of 1. I play a blood toll harpy. And we each lose one life. What happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game is drawn the next time a player gets priority.

See also: [If I simultaneously kill my opponent and deck myself at the same time, is the game drawn?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45331/if-i-simultaneously-kill-my-opponent-and-deck-myself-at-the-same-time-is-the-ga) which covers effectively the same question.